MinIO Object Expiration Based Off Flag
I have a MinIO cluster locally, and I want to be able to set a flag and then after a certain amount of time after that flag was set, the object gets deleted.
I did a bit of research and I found that you can have everything expire after a certain amount of time but I want it to be only items that I set a flag for.
